# How can I use BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker in different sections in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular page with a number of sections in which I use BootstrapPersianDateTimePicker for bootstrap 5 in some of the sections. It works fine at first, but when I switch between sections, it stops working.

index.html

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  
  <link href="assets/vendors/PersianDate/mds.bs.datetimepicker.style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="assets/vendors/PersianDate/mds.bs.datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</body>
```

--->component.ts

```
RunDateScript(){      
      import('src/assets/vendors/bootstrap/RunScript.js'); 
    };
```

--->RunScript.js

```
new mds.MdsPersianDateTimePicker(document.querySelector('#date-text'), {
  targetTextSelector: '#date-text',
  targetDateSelector: '#date-value'
});
```

--->component.html

```
<section *ngIf="isShow=='section1' ">                        
   <div _ngcontent-c15="" class="col-md-4">                                                                        
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date-text" >
   </div>
</section>
<section *ngIf="isShow=='section2' ">

<section>
```